# Running Jconsole from a service: CentOS

Tags: linux, service, jconsole

I installed Tomcat on my CentOS 6.3 machine and I made it a service by creating the `/etc/init.d/tomcat` file.
It works with the basic start, stop, restart and status functionality just fine.

I use jconsole on the servers often, so I thought it would be nice to build this functionality into the service (by running `service tomcat monitor`) instead of having to run `ps aux|grep java` and then running the `jconsole <Java PID>` .

Here is my service script (Just the monitor section):

```
monitor)
        # Check for Tomcat PID (greps are separated to prevent returning the single grep PID)
        FOUND_PID=$(ps aux |grep  $JAVA_HOME/bin/ | grep java |awk -F' ' '{print $2}')
        if [[ $FOUND_PID ]]
        then
                echo -e $JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole $FOUND_PID
                $JAVA_HOME/bin/jconsole $FOUND_PID
        else
                echo -e "Failed: Tomcat is not currently running";
        fi
;;
```

Everything inside of the monitor section works when I run the bash script directly it works, but when the service calls it, it just hangs at the jconsole line and doesn't do anything.

And when I run `service tomcat monitor`, I do get the correct path output, so I know that the path is correct.

Is there a way to get the jconsole to work when called from the services script?